# ActiveX controls not working in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, activex

Internet Explorer blocked ActiveX control downloads for trusted sites even after the following changes in IE8.

1. Added my site as Trusted site.
2. Went to Tools - Internet Options - privacy - unchecked "turn on pop-up Blocker".
3. Went to Tools - Internet Options - security (tab) - Trusted site and internet and local internet

And I made the following changes:

1. Allow previously unused ActiveX control to run without prompt ...* - Enabled
2. Allow Scriptlets - Enabled
3. Automatic prompting for ActiveX controls - disable
4. Binary and script behaviors - Enabled
5. Download signed ActiveXC controls - Enabled
6. Download unsigned ActiveXC controls - Enabled
7. Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as save for...* - Disabled
8. Only allow approved domains to use ActiveX without prompt - disabled
9. Run ActiveX controls and plug-ins - Enable
10. Script ActiveX controls marked safe for scripting* - Enabled
11. Downloads - Automatic prompting for file downloads

After I made this change, still IE blocked me to download ActiveX control and show the pop-up in the top of the website..
So any one please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

check this [link](http://infotech.wsu.edu/security/services/legacyVPN/EnableActiveX-IE.html)
and also you have to check folllowing

under the Scripting enable the Active Scripting.
Go to privacy tab Disable pop Up blocker.